# Keep navigation bar title during search with Searchable

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

Is it possible to not hide the Title in Navigation Bar in search mode using Searchable? Using the code below Title in Navigation Bar is hidden when Search Field is focused.

```
 NavigationView {
        }
        .searchable(text: $viewModel.searchText,
                    placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always),
                    prompt: Strings.selectCity)
    }
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

[image: Like this]

Comment: Apple did this in the Shortcuts app. I'd really like to know how they did that.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for same answer but did not found a solution. So I have added TextFiled instead of `.searchable(text: $searchText,  placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always) )` to:

```
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").foregroundColor(.gray)
    TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
        .font(Font.system(size: 20))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 17.1 this is possible with [searchPresentationToolbarBehavior(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/searchpresentationtoolbarbehavior(_:)) API:

```swift
@State private var searchText = ""

List {
    // ... content
}
.searchable(text: $searchText)
.searchPresentationToolbarBehavior(.avoidHidingContent)
```